# How does the keep mentioned in the Throne card from the Deck of Many Things work?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Part of the description of the Throne card in the [*deck of many things*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things) states:

> In addition, you gain rightful ownership of a small keep somewhere in the world. However, the keep is currently in the hands of monsters, which you must clear out before you can claim the keep as yours.

This means you will have to fight to claim it. But how? Do you have a bunch of random encounters, or is there a number of set battles you need to do?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Deck of Many Things is in the DMG for a reason - it requires DMG adjudication. There are no further rules because it's up to the DM to decide. It's a plot/story call, not a rules/mechanical one.

Answer (score 16):

This card requires the DM to produce an adventure regarding that keep. He might allow the player to design the keep, or do so himself. It's intentionaly vague so that it can be easily fit into almost any storyline.

Answer (score 8):

It's up to the DM to decide how it works. There are no more details. It should probably be an *adventure*.